# Bind Ctrl-Tab to cycle through windows in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux, key-binding

I'm trying to figure out how to bind ctrl-tab to cycle through all open windows, I've tried:
bind-key -n  C-Tab select-window -t :.+
which says Unknown key.

What am I missing?

Note: I don't want to use my prefix keys prior to pressing ctrl-tab, I just want ctrl-tab to cycle through all the panes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my terminal (OS X terminal), when I press C-Tab it treats it the same as a normal tab. To work around that issue you can modify your terminal settings to bind C-Tab to F20 and in tmux bind F20 to next-window.

Comment: Any info on redefining that? xmodmap or something similar? It's not anything I've ever done.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: I use debian and rxvt, but shouldn't there be a way to do it system wide (so if I'm in TTY it'd still work?)

Comment: I'm really not that expert on terminal emulation, but as far as I know, keys to their internal representations mapping is handled by the terminal emulator. For your problem, googling around I found that putting `URxvt.keysym.C-Tab: ^[[19;2~` in your ~/.Xresources binds C-Tab to F20. References:  [1](http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/term-function-keys.html)  [2](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man7/urxvt.7.html) [3](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=71462)